# Two value-based axis for chart in Numbers 3.5

Tags: numbers, iwork

I am trying to achieve a chart in Numbers 3.5 where both axis scale linearly.

Right now, my chart looks like this:
[image: Chart]

Obviously, I want the x-axis to scale because the 100.000 bytes message is MUCH larger than the 10.000 bytes message, and the current chart is misleading.

I can't find a way to do this - the x-axis is always labeled as a "Category" instead of a "Value". Any way to achieve this?

Comment: because your first coulomb is used as category, but you can switch that.

Comment: but how? I can't find a way to switch it.

Comment: what should be your x-axis (category)?

Comment: the message size (as it is now), but it should scale linearly -- so I want the space between 10.000 and 100.000 to be 10x the space between 1.000 and 10.000

Comment: that would be a logarithmic scale

Comment: ok, my math's not that good, but that's not the point, is it? ;-)

Comment: No, BlackWolf, you are right.  You want a linear scale.  Buscar is confused.  BlackWolf's answer is also correct and the best way to do things.  You can't make a line chart in Numbers without an even scale.

Answer (score 3):

Took me a while, but I figured it out: The solution is to choose a scatter plot instead of a line chart.

1. Select **Insert -> Chart -> 2D Scatter**
2. Select the chart, then select **Add Chart Data**:
   [image]
3. Now simply select your entire table, including the x axis. Numbers will figure out the rest and automatically select your leftmost column as the x-axis.
   [image]
4. Finally, to make it look like a line chart, select the chart, then select the "Axis" tab in the inspector Chose **Data Symbols: None** and **Connection Lines: Straight**.

Result:

[image]